# Selectively inline functions (for debugging purposes)?

Tags: c++, inline

What I'd love to have is a build configuration where functions are *not* inlined, *except* some selected functions (that may or may not be inlined, that would be up to the compiler).

Even better would be some kind of an "inlining level", where I could specify such a level for each function, plus a minimum level when building, and only functions above the min level would be allowed to be inlined. I know there's no standard solution for this, but compiler-specific hacks would be just as welcome.

I'd like to be able to step through most of my functions non-inlined in a debugger, but a selected few of them should be inlined, partly for performance reasons, and partly to avoid crazy-deep call stacks. The code involves some pretty nasty template metaprogramming, but that part is mostly done, so I'd like to concentrate on the rest. So it would be nice to have the functions that belong to the template metaprograms inlined, but not the other inline functions.

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Comment: You can use preprocessor macros but what you are describing cannot be controlled at runtime.

Comment: And the same applies to templates. That too is fixed at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't want to control this at runtime. However, I'm not sure what you mean, how would I use macros here? Instead of inline functions? That I'd like to avoid. It would be nice to be able to build either with everything inlined (standard debug build), or just some of the functions; controlled by a compiler switch or something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your compiler, yes.  For g++, the following will work:

```
void foo() __attribute__ ((noinline));
void foo() __attribute__ ((always_inline));
```

On MSVC++:

```
__declspec(noinline) void foo();
__forceinline void foo();
```

Note that g++ **requires** that the attributes be applied only to prototypes, not definitions.  So if your function is definition-only (no separate prototype) then you must create a prototype in order to apply the attribute.  MSVC does not have this requirement.

`__forceinline` specifically has [some exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Make sure you read them carefully so you know whether or not it will have any effect in your particular situation.  g++ does not document any exceptions to the `always_inline` attribute, but some things are readily apparent (inlining a call to a virtual method will only work when the method is called statically, for example).

You can generalize this with macros:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
 #define NOINLINE(x) __declspec(noinline) x
 #define INLINE(X) __forceinline x
#else
 #ifdef __GNUC__
  #define NOINLINE(x) x __attribute__ ((noinline))
  #define INLINE(x) x __attribute__ ((always_inline))
 #else
  #error "I don't know how to force inline/noinline on your compiler."
 #endif
#endif

INLINE(void foo());
NOINLINE(void foo());
```

Comment: Thanks. Would __forceinline / always_inline override the relevant compiler switches (eg. /Ob0 in MSVC)?

Comment: @imre I believe that is their purpose, to override any and all other decision-making processes that the compiler would otherwise use to decide whether or not to inline a particular function.

Comment: @imre : From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx), no: "*Even with `__forceinline`, the compiler cannot inline code in all circumstances. The compiler cannot inline a function if: ... The function or its caller is compiled with /Ob0 (the default option for debug builds).*"

Comment: @ildjarn Guess I didn't page-down enough when reading.  Well, this is at least as close as one can get to fine control over function inlining.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a set of functions you want `inline`d, you can `#define` some macro (assuming GCC or Clang) to `__attribute__(__always_inline__)`, which will

1. Always inline the function
2. give a compile error if that's not possible for technical reasons.